# Error in facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using javascript sdk to update status in facebook. This is my code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'id', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code heres

   FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
 });
   } else {
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.')
   }
});
   };

   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
     (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));
   </script>
```

but i am getting An error occurred message while opening this page.please give a solution to solve this.Or any one else can share the app id which is working fine

Comment: please provide the error description or number

Comment: not getting any error number. this is the error desc ".An error occurred with Dragnshare. Please try again later.

Comment: Post a link to your app, please. "An error occurred" message sounds like a browser message, so it could be any number of errors (javascript, html, missing resource, etc).

Comment: Sounds like the error is with Dragnshare, not Facebook ;)

Comment: please share how i can fix Dragonshare (my app). I am trying local host. please tell how to set the domain names

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/389694921095423/summary/  this is my app uri. please give suggestions

Comment: I have given app domain as local host, website with facebook login:http://localhost:1461/ & Mobile Site URL as http://localhost:/1461.   and now i am trying from another client machine where there is no webserver and not able to access localhost. is there any problem with app settings?

Comment: Try setting your Website with Facebook Login to `http://localhost/`